# WCF service fails on IIS 10 on Server 2019

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I am migrating WCF services to a new 2019 server running IIS10.
The server that these services come from is a IIS8.5 running on Server 2012R2.
It is obvious that a IIS backup/restore might/will fail as a number of discussions will suggest.
I have set up my remote deployment from VS2019 the same as for the old server.
I can deploy webs and REST services without any problems - BUT WCF services fail:

Fiddler reports 404 Not Found.
Calling the service via test programs under debug brings up the following:

> 25-02 11:09:43 [24016] FATAL bSm.Kll.Program - System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:
> at <System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)<br> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

I am reasonable sure that I am missing credentials for the service, the problem is WHERE / WHAT is the additional requirement enforced by this server.

As an aside:
I already ran across the problem that the Web Deployment tool has a extra requirement for a "User delegate" which was quite a hurdle on its own. The 3.6 version of the tool had to be collected from the MS website before this requirement was revealed.

Comment: I have replied your the same thread in Q&A and will continue discuss with you there.

Comment: Sorry @Bruce I do not understand. Please expand your comment

Comment: I think this question may be asked by you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/750827/wcf-service-fails-on-iis-10-on-server-2019.html